# how to replace a variable in middle of reoccuring commands

Tags: command-line, bash, git, grep

I'm in a middle of a merge and I'm trying to find specific variables that went missing in the following way:

- `grep -Rn "<variable string>" <old_branch> | grep -v Binary | grep -v metadata`
- cp a file from the result list that contains the changes I want
- git add -p to said file

These 3 steps are repeated in a loop for every new variable went missing.

My questoins are:

1. Is there a way to change the variable at the end of the command? something like `grep -Rn "<variable string>" <old_branch> | grep -v Binary | grep -v metadata {"my_unique_var_1"}`
2. Is there a better way to filter out unwanted results that would give the same (or better_ results than `| grep -v Binary | grep -v metadata`?
3. Is my general method problematic in any way?

Thanks

Comment: The `Binary` is probably from all the binary files in the `.git `directory, which you should ignore: `grep -Rn "<variable string>" <old_branch> --exclude-dir=.git`. Similarly, if the `metadata` results are from files named metadata, exclude those with `--exclude=metadata`.

Comment: Also, if you're merging, why aren't you using `git mergetool`?